# Remove rows in dataframe based on condition, dataframe vs list boolean?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['letter', 'number']
exclude_list = [2, 4, 6]
```

I want to change row 2 in df, where "number" == 2, to empty/nan. I want to do this by comparing the "number" column to the exclude list, and if there is a match, exclude that row.

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 4):

Check these useful functions:

1. [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) : Lets you replace values where a condition is met, we use the `inplace=True` flag to [perform the operation without using no auxiliary data structure (or significant extra storage in simple words)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm).
2. [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) : To check if values are in another list.

```
    df.number.mask(df.number.isin(exclude_list),inplace=True)
    df
    Out[200]: 
      letter  number
    0      a     1.0
    1      b     NaN
    2      c     3.0
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way for me to make the entire row empty?

Comment: @zliangmdZ `df.mask(df.number.isin(exclude_list),inplace=True)`

Answer (score 2):

`df.loc[df['number'].isin(exclude_list), 'number'] = None`

```
  letter  number
0      a     1.0
1      b     NaN
2      c     3.0
```

For the whole row
`df.loc[df['number'].isin(exclude_list), :] = None`

```
  letter  number
0      a     1.0
1   None     NaN
2      c     3.0
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way for me to make the entire row empty?